# IDA No Search Results in Subview For Viable Address

Tags: ida

I found an address of a function from the game AssaultCube, and the address is `0045BCA0`. In IDA, I disassembled ac_client.exe as a portable executable and tried to search for that address in the subview window with no results. This address is definitely in the actual game. How would I make IDA include more subview addresses so I can find that function address?

**Can't Find Address**

[image: Missing Addresses]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no function has been created at that address for whatever reason. Try jumping to it manually(<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut) and create code/function there.

Comment: Would an address found by pressing the shortcut `G` be different from finding an address in the subview? I did find the address, which got converted into a function, but it looks different than what I expected. Could that be because that function was changed in the actual game?

Comment: with G you can jump to any address inside the file and not only start of a function (e.g. middle of a function, data area, or still undefined bytes).